# Securing small volume distributed web services

Tags: tls

A taxi office has a server, which they use to run a web service, which takes bookings for their drivers.

The volume of requests is small approx. 100 request per hour. The service is used by operators in the office and by members of the public using their smart phones.

If a developer was writing web services where the taxi companies installed the software themselves in their own offices, would there be a way that a login could be secured/encrypted in an automated way at installation to be used by office staff and smartphone users.

Comment: I'm not sure what the volume has to do with the design. I'm also thinking that TLS would be the natural solution to this.

Comment: Do you think that installing a self signed certificate at app installation would be a solution?

Comment: Wait, your design is for each company to install and maintain a web server in their own offices that mobile apps connect to? And you want to secure it "automatically"? I think you need to explain your architecture a lot more.

Comment: With the advent of lightweight Http servers like Nancyfx it should be possible to run a web service on a local server attached to the Internet so long as the volume is low and there is no financial credit card payment details on the server.

Comment: The phrase "attached to the Internet" is no small phrase. If it is so lightweight, then host in the cloud, not locally to offices. You have full control of the setup, you can install certificates, and the local office is not exposed to the traffic and potential vulnerabilities of the software.

Comment: Does "small" imply that there is not a dedicated IT staff at the company?

Comment: No dedicated IT staff. No sensitive data - a booking system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per several of the comments, the downside to this solution is the local installation of a publicly available web service.  The initial requirements just to allow connectivity is greater than the return on the service, you have:

- Public connectivity requirements
- Security requirements, minimal maybe but litigation still can happen over the smallest of issues
- Certificates for each location:  no, self signed is inappropriate and again, a bad choice especially if the web service is used by mobile devices (who hate self-signed certs)
- There is always an IT maintenance SLA somewhere and dispersed installations means dispersed infrastructure and troubleshooting management.

We could go on with other issues, from patch management, to janitors walking in and turning off critical infrastructure.

Per Schroeder, using a lightweight cloud service (AWS or Azure), you can create a single web app space and tenant the application as a subscription so turning up a new taxi service is as simple as you develop it within the application.  it can be a subdomain of the parent service, it can be a separate VM, or it can just be a logon-isolated app.  But the benefits of maintaining a single web service in the cloud starts with:

- Single troubleshooting location
- Easy application availability (redundancy is just one of those cool Cloud things)
  -Infrastructure that eclipses small business on-premise services
- Built-in monitoring, DNS, routing, and networking services.  This is the big one that you don't want to deal with for one-off small office issues.
- Documentation and support - when issues arise, you at least have someone to talk to, compared with vendor A for internet, vendor B for basic networking, vendor C or yourself for dev work (or you're contracting it out at a premium)

Cloud is just the better way to go for these solutions.

Comment: Yes I see I just maybe though the IOT for taxi offices.